# Webapp2 Routes in Google app engine not working

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am running the following code as my GAE application.

```
class HomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('This is the HomeHandler.')

class ProductListHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('This is the ProductListHandler.')

class ProductHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, product_id):
        self.response.write('This is the ProductHandler. '
            'The product id is %s' % product_id)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/', HomeHandler),
    (r'/products', ProductListHandler),
    (r'/products/(\d+)', ProductHandler),
])
```

When I try to access, only '/' route is working (https://myapp.appspot.com) which prints 'This is the HomeHandler'. If I try to access https://myapp.appspot.com/products, I am getting

> **The requested URL /products was not found on this server**

I am new to server side development. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your `app.yaml` is wrongly configured. Make sure you have `.*` in your `url` part.

```
handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```